# what are the benefits of using a spring-boot library instead of the core libs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to use Kafka in my spring-boot application and I see spring-boot has its own spring-kafka library. I am new to spring and java and confused if I should be using spring-kafka or any other application's spring-based lib rather than using the core libraries and what are the benefits of either one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring boot with Kafka comes with various autoconfiguration out-of-the-box to save you from the trouble of configuring each and everything (though you can definitely override spring-boot opinionated autoconfiguration).

- So, if you want a ready-made application to work quickly, you can take the help of spring-boot and its utilities.
- If your preference is configuring each and everything to gain fine control, use core libraries.

I'd say it's just a matter of choice or preference.